# Don't uninstall file with WSPBuilder

Tags: uninstallation, wspbuilder

I am building a WSP file with WSPBuilder.  All my DLL's are added to the file and the WSP install will install them at the proper place (bin, GAC etc...). My problem is that I don't want some of those files to be uninstalled when uninstalling the feature.  How can I do that? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It cant be done. If you really want that edit manifest.xml and remove the entries of the files you dont want to remove. Then try the uninistall. Install/uninstall basically reads manifest.xml for the list of files/references/CAS etc.